# how to change css class dynamically with angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I am using bootstrap4 navs with a form
I am trying to change the css class to display: none; for every tab that is not selected
I have tried to make this happen by using ngClass but didn't work
[stackblitz  demo](http://%20https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-szkxtx)

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="itemSummary-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#itemSummary" role="tab" aria-controls="itemSummary" aria-selected="true">Item Summary</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="details-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#details" role="tab" aria-controls="details" aria-selected="false">Details</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="measurement-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#measurement" role="tab" aria-controls="measurement" aria-selected="false">Measurement</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

     <div class="tab-pane fade show active" ngClass="!active? display:none" id="itemSummary" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="itemSummary-tab"> 
    ....
    </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="measurement" ngClass="!active? display:none" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="measurement-tab">
...
</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="details" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="details-tab">
...
</div>
```

Comment: Try https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

Comment: Create one demo link on stackblitz.com if you arent getting any solution. Will try to work on that code

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-szkxtx   here is my stackblitz demo for my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p6mmwz?file=src/app/app.component.html) code.

Created a method in `ts` file as:

```
  activateClass(tab) {
    this.selectedTabName = tab;
  }
```

and in **html**

```
    <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs"  (click)="activateClass(tab)" class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="{{tab}}-tab" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': (selectedTabName === tab) ? 'red' : 'black' }" data-toggle="tab" href="#{{tab}}" role="tab" >{{tab}}</a>
    </li>
```

replace above code of `[ngStyle]` , with below one to meet your requirement of `display:none`

```
[ngStyle]="{'display': (selectedTabName === tab) ? '' : 'none' }"
```

*Not sure how will someone ever select another tab when it in `display:none` state*

Answer (score 2):

Here is from the docs https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

`<some-element [ngClass]="{'class1 class2 class3' : true}">...</some-element>`

But since you are just trying to set a single style Shashank Vivek is right that you should instead try https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle `<some-element [ngStyle]="{'font-style': styleExp}">...</some-element>`

Which would make your example (you need the square brackets!):

`<some-element [ngStyle]="{ 'display: none': !active }">...</some-element>`

This sets `display: none` when `active === false`

Answer (score 2):

You can assign class to an element using ngClass Directive.

```
<p
  [ngClass]="{
  'red': classStyle,
  'green': !classStyle}">
  Dynamic classes
</p>
```

**css**

```
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using conditional classes
ref
https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-ngclass/